# javascript error in ASP.NET content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test1(w) {
        document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').style.width = w;
        return false;
    }
    Test1(10); // This line arises an error. Why ?
</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Test1(10)" />
</asp:Content>
```

I get error when the function Test1(10) is called from the script. But when it called on the click of button, it works fine. How can I call the function from the script(OR how I can access the `onload()` function in an `ASP.NET Content Page`)?

Comment: you should wait until the document is loaded

Answer (score 1):

When your call to "Test1()" inside the `<script>` block happens, that input field is not yet part of the DOM. Thus the call to `getElementById()` will return `null` and the first line of the function will fail.

If you move the `<script>` block to *after* the text box, it should work.

*edit* — also you may want to explicitly append "px" to your width.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test1(w) {
        document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').style.width = w;
        return false;
    }
window.onload = function() {
    Test1(10); // This line arises an error. Why ?
}
</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Test1(10)" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the textbox doesn't exist when you execute Test1 in the script.  You either have to place the call in a document.ready function or move it further down the page, after the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you every time you want to execute javascript code, even directly from the  tag ether from events you have to wait to load the dom level.
So can do something like :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload =function()
      { /* code */ }
  </script>
```

Or execute your code in the "onload" event of the body tag:
like

```
    <body onload="Test1(10);">
    </body>
```

Or if you use JQuery you can use the above :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        /* Code to execute */
      });
  </script>
```